# The osrmRoute (osrm package) based function I created doesn't extract and store the output correctly

Tags: r, function, osrm

Working in R, I have a data frame with multiple entries of lat,lon coordinates of a starting point and and arrival point lat_end, lon_end:

```
df <- data.frame(
  lat = c(44.88358, 44.88358, 44.88358, 44.88358, 44.88358, 44.88358, 44.88358),
  lon = c(-93.13827, -93.13827, -93.13827, -93.13827, -93.13827, -93.13827, -93.13827),
  lat_end = c(42.06886, 42.06886, 42.06886, 42.06886, 42.14877, 43.95747, 46.14061),
  lon_end = c(-72.61516, -72.61516, -72.61516, -72.61516, -72.60711, -96.19531, -68.04002)
)

print(df)
```

I have created a function based on osrmRoute function that should calculate the travel distance in km for each row of coordinates:

```
calculate_travel_distance <- function(df) {
  distances <- vector("numeric", nrow(df))  # Create an empty numeric vector
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    src <- st_as_sf(df[i, c("lon", "lat")], coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)   # Source waypoint (lon, lat)
    dst <- st_as_sf(df[i, c("lon_end", "lat_end")], coords = c("lon_end", "lat_end"), crs = 4326)   # Destination waypoint (lon, lat)
    
    route <- osrmRoute(src = src, dst = dst, overview = "full")
    
    print(route)  # Print the route object for inspection
    
    if (!is.null(route) && route$status == "Ok" && !is.null(route$routes)) {
      travel_distance <- route$routes$distance
      distances[i] <- travel_distance
    } else {
      distances[i] <- NA
    }
  }
  
  return(distances)
}
```

Running the function on the dataframe the output correctly identify the distances (i just report the first row output) but doesn't extract it and store it correctly in the "distance" vector:

```
distances <- calculate_travel_distance(df)

> distance <- calculate_travel_distance(df)
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 4 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -93.13828 ymin: 40.9438 xmax: -72.58549 ymax: 44.96499
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
    src dst duration distance                       geometry
1_1   1   1 1476.882  2125.38 LINESTRING (-93.13828 44.88...
```

where the distance 2125.38 is correct but the vector still gives only "NA" values:

```
print(distances)
> print(distances)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: The problem comes from the `if/else`. Line `if (!is.null(route) && route$status == "Ok" && !is.null(route$routes))` returns systematically false, so the vector is filled with `NA`. In the `sf` output `route`, there is no `status` column, nor `routes`.